# Error 2020: Got packet bigger than max_allowed_packet' when dumping one row from the table

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, mysql-8.0

I got the error message when I ran mysqldump:

```
Error 2020: Got packet bigger than max_allowed_packet' bytes when dumping table `my_table` at row: 17223\n"
```

According to the [MySQL official user guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/packet-too-large.html#:%7E:text=The%20largest%20possible%20packet%20that,server%20or%20client%20is%201GB.):

> The largest possible packet that can be transmitted to or from a MySQL
> 8.0 server or client is 1GB.

I have changed max_allowed_packet to 1G and restart MySQL service:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';
+--------------------+------------+
| Variable_name      | Value      |
+--------------------+------------+
| max_allowed_packet | 1073741824 |
+--------------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But still got the same error from the mysqldump. Is there any other way I can fix this error?

I am very new to MySQL, any help is appreciated!

Comment: If the packet size exceeds `max_allowed_packet` value then retrievind the data by chunks is the only option. `mysqldump` have no such option, hence you'd must search for another dumping technique. But I'd recommend you to find the source of such huge packet.

Comment: *I have changed max_allowed_packet to 1G and restart MySQL service* By fact you increase the memory consumption without any profit. You'd set the session variable value.

Comment: Can you `SELECT` the one row?  Can you do `SELECT LENGTH(long_column) FROM ...`?